# Getting the right User.Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having a little bit of trouble with MVC HttpContext.User.Identity I'm getting the system.security.principal.windowsIdentity and it's giving me the name of my windows user... I don't want that, I want to get the (at first) null User.Identity so I can use FormsAuthentication. How can I prevent the mvc to use this system.security.principal.windowsIdentity to show up the right User.Identity? Any help would be appreciated

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var s = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; //
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `<system.web>` section of your web.config file, change to forms authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have windows authentication enabled. You probably are in the same domain as your webserver so it will authenticate you automaticly. Turn it off or be explicit about authentication in your configuration.

Comment: Yep! Completely forgot about that! It worked... Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

check the web.config to ensure `<authentication mode="Forms" />` if you didn't set this explicitly, then you probably selected the mvc intranet template when you first created the project.

once the config file is updated you will also need to create the login/off actions and views. you may want to create another project using the internet template and pull out the authentication components.

intranet template defaults to windows authentication while internet template defaults to form.